# how to make json metadata database for vuforia cloud recognition

Tags: android, json, vuforia

I am using Vuforia cloud recognition sample for android. I wanted to change the target image and the Augmentation object (3d model, video streaming, images). 
As I understand I'll have to create the Json metadata and or some kind of database on my remote server which will provide me augmentation object, same way as samplebook1.json in cloudreco sample.
 can somebody please clarify me and point me in right direction?
How do I create json metadata? how do I create a database? how do i integrate with my application?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20185386/what-is-metadata-how-do-i-create-a-metadata-and-how-do-i-associate-it-to-a-clou

Answer (score 0):

I found this discussion too :
https://developer.vuforia.com/forum/cloud-recognition/time-update-metadata&sort=1